# MySQl 5.5 doesn't truncate VARCHARs when they're longer than expected

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I've this problem: before 5.5 mySQL (using myISAM tables) used to truncate VARCHAR types to the column length. Now, starting with the abovementioned version, it doesn't anymore. It's a huge problem as it breaks my app (I know there shouldn't be such problem, but I didn't do that... I just have to cope with it, so please be patient). Is there a way to set this behaviour in 5.5?

I tried to set SQL-MODE = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" as I read somewhere it would help... It doesn't....

I even suspect I can solve this by setting some parameter in the JDBC driver I'm using, yeah, sorry it's a java app, I forgot...

Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in a parameter of JDBC driver. In fact it was set to throw exceptions in case of truncation. Changing the configuration solved it.

Answer (score 0):

What SQL_MODE are you using? Is it the same one you used before upgrading to 5.5? I suspect it is not.

I'm running 5.5.8 with SQL_MODE = '' and the implicit truncation still works the same as it did in older versions (5.0, 5.1, etc.)

So I suspect your problem is that you changed SQL_MODE, not that you upgraded to 5.5.

Check current SQL_MODE:

```
SELECT @@SQL_MODE;
```

Set SQL_MODE to '':

```
SET SQL_MODE = '';
```